# Something similar to PHP's SimpleXML in Python?

Tags: php, python, xml, simplexml

Is there a way in Python to handle XML files similar to the way PHP's SimpleXML extension does them?

Ideally I just want to be able to access certain xml datas from a list object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a long list of libraries associated with XML processing on the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml). Note that a number of them are included in the standard library. Most of them will do what you are looking for:

> to access certain xml datas from a list object

which is a bit vague, and perhaps some more concrete use-case might narrow down that list for you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)  It provides many easy ways to access read xml and  to build new xml.

Or better yet use [lxml.etree](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html) that provides even more convenient ways of accessing the nodes (such as xpath)

Answer (score 1):

You might be referring to something like this:

http://github.com/joestump/python-simplexml

I haven't used it myself, but I was also looking for something like simplexml in PHP and this link showed up.

Answer (score 0):

[lxml.objectify](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) does exactly what you want

```
In [1]: from lxml import objectify

In [2]: x = objectify.fromstring("""<response><version>1.2</version><amount>1.01</amount><currency>USD</currency></response>""")

In [3]: x.version
Out[3]: 1.2

In [4]: x.amount
Out[4]: 1.01

In [5]: x.currency
Out[5]: 'USD'
```